# Undefined index: catalog.topnav on local installation

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, frontend, fatal-error

I downloaded the code from the server, and once it's setup locally, I can access the admin area just fine, but when I go to the frontend I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: catalog.topnav  in \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 460

#0 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(460): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', 'E:\\Code\\work\\pe...', 460, Array)
#1 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
#2 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
#3 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#11 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#12 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 \path-to-folder\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 \path-to-folder\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 \path-to-folder\index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `catalog.topnav` looks like inside a cms page. Do you have magento developer mode enabled?

Comment: Yes @rob3000, it's enabled

Comment: If you need urgent access to the backend you can diasble developer mode.  As for the actual error it looks like you're trying to add `catalog.topnav` block to the topnav reference. Have you installed the latest magento patch?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I used TemplateMonster MegaMenu module. When I disable this module the error is not appear.